# Logistic regression with non-negative parameter

Tags: logistic, classification

I want to model the probability of a binary variable x given some predictor, d.  It needs two parameters:

- One parameter that sets the "break point", at which p(x=1 | d) = 0.5.
- One parameter that sets the "softness", i.e. how abruptly the probability changes around the break point.

(Sorry I'm sure there's standard terminology for this, but I'm a bit of a novice.)

A logistic regression model feels like the right approach, but the domain of d is [0, inf] (d is a distance metric).  Is there a standard way to transform d to [-inf, inf] so a logistic regression can be used (e.g. f(x) = x-1/x)?   Or is there another common model for this kind of scenario?

Comment: Is d a parameter of the logistic regression or a predictor used in logistic regression? It sounds like a predictor but you call it a parameter. If it is a predictor, then its domain is irrelevant.

Comment: d is the predictor.   Thanks for correcting me, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logistic regression satisfies your requirements -- two parameters controlling the mid-point and the rate of change. But there is no restriction on the domain of predictors. You can just fit a logistic regression using d as it is.

However, if d is highly skewed (as it might be with that domain), then taking a log of d may be useful to prevent the fit being dominated by a few observations.

If d includes exact zeros, then you obviously can't take logs. In that case, if you still think you need a transformation, then I'd use an [inverse hyperbolic sine transformation](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/transformations/).

Comment: BTW, I just took the log of d.  d can include zeros, but the logistic function maps that to zero, which is what I wanted.